# CSS order and selection

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to override a Bootstrap specification.  I have a scaffold file ahead of the Bootstrap file.  However, the Bootstrap specification is being selected, providing White instead of Green.  Why is this happening?

I understand that the A tag has 4 pseudo classes: link, hover, active and visited.  I am just dealing with reality and Bootstrap.

The selector is:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
```

The combined CSS file has these related specifications in this order:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

A picture of the selection:
[image]

All help appreciated.

Comment: I hate it when I do that.

Comment: @Jeroen Please post your response as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does make sense, right? The latter spec overwrites the first one. You have two options:

- Change the order of the declarations;
- Make your spec more specific (a more specific selector, or use `!important` if you need a last resort).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
!important
```

Add the end of you css line That is overwritten. Or change the order of your css.